# How does toArray() function make sure that a list of long type can't be converted to array of Integer

Tags: java, generics

```
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
            int size = size();
            if (a.length < size)
                return Arrays.copyOf(this.a, size,
                                     (Class<? extends T[]>) a.getClass());
            System.arraycopy(this.a, 0, a, 0, size);
            if (a.length > size)
                a[size] = null;
            return a;
    }        

    public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));
        return copy;
    }
```

Not getting why the third parameter type for function copyOf() is `Class<? extends T[]>` and not simply `Class<T[]>` . What make's the difference between them here. Is this constraint making sure that one type of list can't be converted to other type of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard allows you to pass in non-literal classes.

For example:

```
copyOf(new String[0], 0, String[].class);
copyOf(new String[0], 0, new String[0].getClass());
```

Both of these are valid when the third parameter type is `Class<? extends T[]>`; but only the first is valid for `Class<T[]>`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/H7uXvz)

Practically, this means that you are able to invoke `copyOf` for types you don't know at compile time; instead, you are obtaining the class from an existing array.

Comment: What's the difference between String[].class and new String[0].getClass() here ? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: `String[].class` is a class literal: it has type `Class<String[]>`. `new String[0].getClass()` is just invoking `getClass()` on an instance: it has type `Class<? extends String[]>`, because, in general, a reference may point to a subclass, as opposed to an instance of the exact class.

Comment: Is the copyOf function signature `Class<? extends T[]>`  is used here just to make it possible to pass `new String[0].getClass()` too or it has more logical significance inside function.

Answer (score 0):

In java, Array is [covariance](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc)

> In Java, Integer[] is a subclass of Number[], and they are both subclasses of Object[]. This is called covariance.

In your case, that means it accept all array which is subtype of T as parameter. Obviously, more flexible than T[].